# Would it be possible to implement a setTimeout in the Redux Store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, settimeout

I was wondering if it was possible to store a setTimeout in the Redux Store and have the setTimeout trigger an even. From what I am learning, actions are javascript objects but I am unsure on how it will interact with the store.

Initially I was thinking something like this

```
const timer = setTimeout(() => {someFunc}, 1000);
```

action:

```
const t = (timer) => {
  return {
    type:TIMER_START,
    timer
  }
};
```

reducer:

```
tReducer = (state={timer:null}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case TIMER_START:
      return {...state, timer: action.timer}
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Would this be a valid way of implementing a timeout in the store? And if so,  would it be possible to cancel the timeout? Since we want pure functions in Redux I am unsure about whether we can cancel the timeout

Comment: what are u trying to achieve?

Comment: @SultanH. I want a message to pop a message after a certain amount of time but reset if the user closes the message

Comment: Do you already have them? like an Array of messages that are going to be displayed one after the other? or do they come separately?

Comment: They will be coming separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions must be plain objects, with no side effects. To dispatch async actions you should use a custom middleware, like `redux-saga` or `redux-thunk`. An example of async action with `redux-thunk`:

```
const storeUsers = () =>{
    return dispatch =>{
        setTimeOut(() => dispatch({type: 'SENDED_AFTER_3_SECONDS'}), 3000)
    }
}
```

Comment: with the middleware, would it be possible to dispatch an action after a set time or only stuff similar to your example?

Comment: Thanks! So with this, I can call storeUsers to send the delayed action, is the right?

Comment: Yes, but you have to configure `redux-thunk` before. Check [this article](https://alligator.io/redux/redux-thunk/).